# Join two battery operated LED light strings

Tags: led, ac-dc

I have two 2 meter LED lights strings (lights are in plastic flower) that I would like to power using AC to DC universal adapter.

Currently the LED lights are powered by 2 AA Batteries with a switch on the battery box.

I got a 240V AC to DC adaptor with some DC output voltage options.

My questions.

1. Must I set the adaptor to 6V or 3V for the strings if join the 2 LED strings?
2. Should I use two adaptors and each set to 3V instead?
3. Is this a fire hazard I am creating?
4. Is there a better way to achieve this task?

[image: LED in flower]
[image: 2xAA Battery Box]
[image: AC to DC universal adaptor]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 3 V.
2. No need as long as it can provide enough current to drive both.
3. Unlikely.
4. My only concern would be the open circuit voltage in the 3 V setting on it. Measure it with a multimeter. If way high, say >4 V, not good. If regulated to close to 3 V, good to go.